# Ember - outputting a hash in the view but nothing is showing up

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a hash defined inside my routes. I want to access this hash and output the values in my Ember view.

***route/service-signups.js***

```
model: function(){
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    defaultServiceSignups: {
      service_1: false,
      service_2: false,
      service_3: true
    }
  });
}
```

In my view (***service-signups.hbs***), I am trying to iterate through my hash and output the value:

```
{{#each model.defaultServiceSignups }}
  {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

Why do I not see anything in the view? It is completely blank.

**Edit 1:**

I tried to see if I can output anything if the hash is empty, but even the following code below is not outputting anything:

```
{{#each model.defaultServiceSignups }}
  <li>Something is present</li>
{{else}}
  <li>Sorry nothing is there</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: What version of Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `each-in` helper, new as of `2.0`.

```
{{#each-in model.defaultServiceSignups as |key value| }}
  {{key}} Value = {{value}}
{{/each-in}}
```

See the documentation [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_each-in-helper)

Also, from the docs - Note that this helper is unbound. Adding a new property to items will not cause a rerender, but `model.set('defaultServiceSignups', someHash)` will.

**Pre Ember 2.0 -**

You could create a helper `hash-printer` with the following body:

```
hash = params[0]
string = ''
Object.keys(hash).forEach (key) =>
    string += key + ' Value = ' + hash[key] + '<BR>'
return Ember.String.htmlSafe(string)
```

And call it:

```
hash-printer model.defaultServiceSignups
```

If you need more complex functionality create a component, pass the hash into it, and process it in a similar way to the helper I've outlined.

Comment: it looks like `each-in` is only available in ember 2.0 beta. i've tried using it, but the helper does not exist in my project

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I was hoping there would be an easier pre-packaged solution.